# How to add items to a string array from a dropdownlist

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a dropdownlist (`specialty`) and I want to loop through the number of options in the specialty and add it an array:

```
string[] strSpecArrayForTopics = new string[Specialty.Items.Count]; //total number of specialty items
foreach (ListItem li in Specialty.Items) //for each item in the dropdownlist
{
    strSpecArrayForTopics[Specialty.Items.Count] = li.Value; //add the value to the array (The error happens here)
    lblSpec.Text = lblSpec.Text + "<br />" + li.Value; //this works fine.
}
```

So let's say the specialty dropdownlist has:

```
All
Card
Intern
Rad
```

The array should be:

```
strSpecArrayForTopics[0] = "All";
strSpecArrayForTopics[1] = "Card";
strSpecArrayForTopics[2] = "Intern";
strSpecArrayForTopics[4] = "Rad";
```

Comment: What is your question? What is the error?
Think about that, and I think you might get a hand of it yourself ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add index to your array. Check the below code:

```
string[] strSpecArrayForTopics = new string[Specialty.Items.Count]; //total number of specialty items
int index = 0;
foreach (ListItem li in Specialty.Items) //for each item in the dropdownlist
{
    strSpecArrayForTopics[index] = li.Value; //add the value to the array (The error happens here)
    lblSpec.Text = lblSpec.Text + "<br />" + li.Value; //this works fine.
    index = index + 1;
}
```

Comment: I beat you to it ;) Thanks for your response though.

Comment: @SearchForKnowledge: Yeah!!! Great to found your answer on your own. Great job!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
var strSpecArrayForTopics = Specialty.Items.Cast<ListItem>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a `for` loop.

```
for(int i = 0;i < Specialty.Items.Count; i++) //for each item in the dropdownlist
{
    strSpecArrayForTopics[i] = Specialty.Items[i].Value; 
    lblSpec.Text = lblSpec.Text + "<br />" + Specialty.Items[i].Value; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I also used this as a solution:

```
string[] strSpecArrayForTopics = new string[Specialty.Items.Count];
int k = 0;
foreach (ListItem li in Specialty.Items)
{

    strSpecArrayForTopics[k] = li.Value;
    lblSpec.Text = lblSpec.Text + "<br />" + li.Value;
    k++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use LINQ for this.

```
using System.Linq;

string[] strSpecArrayForTopics = Specialty.Items.Select(v => v.Value).ToArray();
```

if `.Value` is of type `object`, use the following.

```
string[] strSpecArrayForTopics = Specialty.Items.Select(v => (string)v.Value).ToArray();
```